# Removing decimal part from float field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, remove, double

I have a field called `"_mean"` and I would like to remove the decimal part of all the values of that field.

I attach two pictures. One an example of my variable (`"_mean"`) in the attribute table and another the type of variable which `"_mean"` is. I am trying doing something like this [Remove decimal points from string field using field calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188488/remove-decimal-points-from-string-field-using-field-calculator) but it does not work. My version of QGIS is 3.24.0.

In the example, I would like that my variable _mean takes a values of 710000 instead of 710000.000000000000000

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to create a new field using `to_int()` or `round()`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Erik. I do not know what is to_int() or round(). I am new in QGIS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) to create a new field with `Precision` = 0. Setting your expression to `"_mean"` will carry through the values to your new field.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can also use the `round` function, which in this case could look like:

```
round(0)
```

where 0 means, that no decimals are to be returned